# How to rename the node of a JTree only after clicking pop-up menu item?

Tags: java, swing, rename, jtree, jpopupmenu

I want to rename the selected node after right-clicking there will be a popup menu containing rename and delete button which will do rename and delete operation after a single click (action listener).
And also this popup menu should not be displayed after clicking on any parent node means it must be leaf-node.

[image: here is the Jtree with popup menu with 'rename' item]

Comment: only rename operation is left also I am getting that right click popup menu on parent node and all over the panel as well, I want it to be popup after right click on leaf node which is selected node

Comment: [Edit] to add a [mre] of the current functionality. While editing, it might be best to remove the part starting *"And also.."*

Answer (score 0):

```
node.setUserObject(newName);
panelOfTheTree.repaint();
panelOfTheTree.revalidate();
```

Regarding the constraint of only being displayed on leaf nodes there are several ways to do this. One way is to implement a MouseListener on the jtree:

```
tree.addMouseListener(new MouseListener(){
   //...
   @Override
   public void MouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
       if(e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3){ //right click
          //get node
          TreePath destinationPath = tree.getClosestPathForLocation(e.getX(), e.getY());
          DefaultMutableTreeNode nodeClicked = (DefaultMutableTreeNode)destinationPath.getLastPathComponent();
          if(nodeClicked .isLeaf()){
               //... build jpopupmenu
          }
               
       }
   }

});
```

Comment: final TreePopup treePopup = new TreePopup(jtree);
treePopup.show(jtree, e.getX(), e.getY());   this is How I build jpopupmenu but this popup menu is being displayed anywhere on the container contaning jtree after right click I want it to be displayed only after right click on selected area of node of jtree. How can I do this.

Comment: Use this, if(tree.getLastSelectedPathComponent() != null) { //now u can show the popup menu}